# External Service is encoding @ symbol when making callout - how to get around this?

Tags: external-services

I am running into an issue with an external service that involved sending an email address in the  callout URI.

The API I am calling is this one: https://developer.everest.validity.com/#bc0f96ba-bf72-45c3-82ed-36a2dc356e8a

The format is like:

```
https://api.everest.validity.com/api/2.0/validation/address/ben@email.com.au
```

However, the external service is sending this:

```
https://api.everest.validity.com/api/2.0/validation/address/ben%40email.com.au
```

This is causing an error **400 Bad Request: Invalid email address.**

This automatic encoding seems to be a feature of OpenAPI 2.0. OpenAPI 3.0 has an option to `allowReserved: true` to prevent the encoding of symbols, but no v2.0

Does anyone know how I can prevent the @ symbol being encoded?

Full External Service schema is below. The "Email" parameter is the one in question.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "defaultDescription",
    "version": "0.1",
    "title": "defaultTitle"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/2.0/validation/address/{Email}": {
      "get": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "X-API-KEY",
            "in": "header",
            "description": "",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
          },
         {
            "name": "Email",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "allowReserved": "true"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Definition generated from Swagger Inspector",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Model0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Meta": {},
    "Diagnostics": {
      "properties": {
        "role_address": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "disposable": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "typo": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    },
    "Results": {
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "definition": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "reasons": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "risk": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "recommendation": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "diagnostics": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Diagnostics"
        }
      }
    },
    "Model0": {
      "properties": {
        "meta": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Meta"
        },
        "results": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Results"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `allowReserved` only applies to [query parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/), it won't help you. External Services is encoding correctly, the consumer is buggy. As a workaround, you can send the request to a proxy. re-encode the path and then send it on to the originally intended destination. You can even create your own REST service in SF to act as a proxy.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I've reached out to the consumer support team to ask about the lack of support for encoded characters. Thanks for the suggested solution.